# Perl - Need to call system('diff') over and over

Tags: perl, system, diff

I have a batch processing system that needs to run the same shell command over and over again.

```
while (x)
{
  if (y)
  {
    $diff = `diff $f1 $f2`;
    ...
  }
  else
  {
    ...
...
```

This is a bit slow so I'm wondering if there's some way to make the shell or program persistent (or something) such that it doesn't have the big overhead every time.

Note that I cannot really consider writing my own `diff` function as the actual output needs to look like it did come from that program.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's some way to make the shell or program persistent (or something) such that it doesn't have the big overhead every time.

Not really. `diff` is kind of inherently a one-shot tool; it doesn't have any persistent mode.

What you may want to have a look at, though, is the [Text::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Diff) module. It can generate output in the same format as the `diff` utility.

Comment: Algorithm::Diff does the work for Text::Diff, and it's written in Perl. It's not going to be faster

Comment: @ikegami There is also [Algorithm::Diff::Xs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Diff::XS)

Comment: @ikegami If the files are all really small, running the comparison in-process might still be an improvement. This would be especially true if the OP is on an operating system which is slow to launch processes, like Windows.